# How Can You Use SciptDb Query Output To a UI label Text?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Consider:

```
function submit(e) {


var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  // Clear the values from the text boxes so that new values can be entered
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('description').setValue('');
  app.getElementById('model').setValue('');
  app.getElementById('productCode').setValue('');
  // Make the status line visible and tell the user the possible actions
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var results = db.query({BarCode:'productCode'});

  app.getElementById('result').setVisible(true).setText(Utilities.jsonStringify(results));
  return app;
}​
```

It only Outputs The Following and not The result:

```
ScriptDb Object
```

This script is used on Google Script with ScriptDB and I want to output a String Answer from the query .

Answer (score 0):

The `results` from `db.query()` are not an object containing data, rather the [ScriptDbResult](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script-db/script-db-result) instance is akin to an iterator, with `hasNext()` and `next()` methods to retrieve data objects. This is explained in the [ScriptDb documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb?hl=en#querying_the_database), but here's how you would apply those examples to your code:

```
function submit(e) {
  // Clear the values from the text boxes so that new values can be entered
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('description').setValue('');
  app.getElementById('model').setValue('');
  app.getElementById('productCode').setValue('');

  // Make the status line visible and tell the user the possible actions
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var results = db.query({BarCode:'productCode'});
  var output = "";
  while (results.hasNext()) {
    var item = results.next()
    output += item.toJson();
  }

  app.getElementById('result').setVisible(true).setText(output);
  return app;
}
```

Alternatively, if you trust that you will have just one match in your query, you could do this:

```
app.getElementById('result')
   .setVisible(true)
   .setText(Utilities.jsonStringify(results.next()));
```